# Is 'Kind attention' impolite? When is it specifically used?

Tags: word-choice

I have often seen emails and letters that contain the phrases:

> For Your Kind Attention, Dr. Maulik: 
>   Kind Attention, Dr. Maulik:

And in other emails/letters I don't find it. To be frank, though as it includes the word *kind*, it looks like a bit of oxymoronic usage with the word *attention*. In other words, a bit impolite! It seems you are *ordering* someone though politely.

In what circumstances do we use this phrase? Is it impolite? If yes, what are the other alternatives to this that serve the *exact* purpose?

Comment: Why do you think that it's an oxymoron?

Comment: It seems to **me** joining two words - kindly and attention. Something like *pretty ugly.* Kindly refers to kindness but attention takes away that politeness - I already said, to me, it **looks so**

Comment: Could you say more about the source and locale of the communications you mentioned? My guess is its likely very formal matters, and as StoneyB said probably not AmE.

Comment: @MaulikV An oxymoron involves contradictory elements. I see nothing contradictory (ie not *kind*) about the word *attention*. It seems neutral to me. *Kind brutality* would be an oxymoron.

Comment: It seems your problem stems from the words _attention_. Although that _can_ be an order (hey! pay attention!), it usually is very neutral: (May I bring to your attention...). You could read _consideration_ in that sentence - would it still feel "wrong" to you?

Comment: I can clearly see the conflict you mention. But I just don't read it that way. Just like "Dear Sir" doesn't really means they hold me "dear" in their hearts.  To me (AmE, US, 49yr), **For your kind attention** seems civil and polite. But I'm **familiar with the style.** My first job was working for my grandfather, a business attorney, and I saw letters like this all the time, both to him and from him, for all kinds of requests, many of which were just requests for copies or signatures or something. So I learned the protocol-nature of the meaning of this phrase.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a derivative (and I think a misunderstanding) of the stock 18th- and 19th-century formal closing: ***Thank you*** for your kind attention (i.e., for your kindness in attending to this letter and the matters it addresses).

It is not to the best of my knowledge used in US correspondence, even very stiff commercial correspondence.

It is not rude, but I do not see that it serves any useful purpose. Presumably the recipients of your communications understand that you expect they will attend to it, and that you hope that they will do so kindly. This sort of “pray forgive my intruding my trivial concerns upon your valuable time” has long since passed its vogue; at least in the US, today’s correspondents would rather you came to the point without affecting a probably insincere and certainly annoying humility.

Comment: Not used in any US correspondence? I din' know about it. But I edited my post...don't you think it looks *ordering* someone though politely!

Answer (score 1):

This phrase is not used in modern American English whatsoever. It immediately conjures up foreigner spam email scammers. You can just end the email with "Thank  you" or "Thank you for your attention" but the last one sounds rather formal.